# Pass arbitrary rowtype as parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

Let's say I have a FOR loop like this:

```
FOR recs IN (SELECT table1.col, table2.col FROM TabA table1, TabB table2) 
LOOP
    renderRec(recs);
END LOOP;
```

And I need to make a procedure like this:

```
PROCEDURE renderRec(inRec IN ????) AS ...
```

How would I define the "recs" parameter for renderRec(), since it's not like a simple table%rowtype etc?

Comment: The usual way is to create a package; in the package you can create the type, and then use it as the data type of your procedure parameter. This is a form of "encapsulation" - keep the data type and the procedure that needs it together.

Comment: Why not pass a `refcursor` for the query to the procedure and operate on all rows (if that's what u need) inside the procedure itself?. Looping through a select and calling procedure doesn't sound like a good idea,especially if the query returns large number of rows.

Comment: What does renderrec() do? Any answer would have to know that. @KaushikNayak is definitely getting you on the right track with a `refcursor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far i could understand your requirement, you wanted to pass all the records from the query `(SELECT table1.col, table2.col FROM TabA table1, TabB table2)` to your procedure `renderRec` and the problem you face is while running the resultset of the query in `For Loop`, you don't know what dataype should be passed to the procedure. Ofcourse others have suggested the use of `refcursor` which might be one way of doing. But i would go with another way by creating a object and then passing the object to the `procedure`. You will see that i am using `BULK` operation inplace of `FOR LOOP` which is the fastest and easiest way. See below and read my comments inline for understanding:

--Table Setup

```
create table tabA(col number);
/
insert into taba values(1);
insert into taba values(2);
insert into taba values(3);
/
create table tabB(col number);
/
insert into tabb values(11);
insert into tabb values(22);
insert into tabb values(33);

commit;
```

--Object created with columns same as of query resultset to hold the result

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Type rec is OBJECT
(
 col1 number,
 col2 number
);
```

--Created a table of Object to hold multiple resultset

```
Create or replace Type var_rec is table of rec ;
/
```

-Procedure which takes resultset of the query in 1 go and display it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE renderRec(inpt IN var_rec)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN 1..inpt.count
  LOOP
    --displaying the resultset got from the select query
    dbms_output.put_line(inpt(rec).col1 ||'--'||inpt(rec).col2 );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

--Anoymous block to pass on the values of the query to the procedure

```
DECLARE
  v_recs var_rec:=var_rec();
BEGIN
  SELECT rec(table1.col,
             table2.col) 
  bulk collect  INTO v_recs
  FROM TabA table1,
    TabB table2 ;

  --Passing the resultset of the above query to the procedure.
  renderRec(v_recs);
END;
```